# Regex to match one tag and not the other in image-dired

Tags: regular-expressions, image-dired

In image-dired I use `M-x` `image-dired-mark-tagged-files` to mark files containing a tag using regexp. e.g. `oil`.

What regex do I need to mark `oil` but *not* `wip` (work in progress).

Input:

```
/foo/IMG_2022.JPG;art;oil;wip
/foo/IMG_2023.JPG;oil;art;
```

Output needed:

```
/foo/IMG_2023.JPG;oil;art;
```

### `M-x` image-dired-mark-tagged-files

image-dired-mark-tagged-files is an autoloaded interactive compiled Lisp
function in ‘image-dired.el’.

(image-dired-mark-tagged-files)

Use regexp to mark files with matching tag.
A ‘tag’ is a keyword, a piece of meta data, associated with an
image file and stored in image-dired’s database file.  This command
lets you input a regexp and this will be matched against all tags
on all image files in the database file.  The files that have a
matching tag will be marked in the dired buffer.

Comment: An Elisp regexp can't express this, AFAIK. But you can do it in two steps: (1) match `oil` marking all such matches, (2) match `wip` to UNmark all of those matches. If no one contradicts this, by proposing a single-regexp answer, then I can add this comment as an answer.

Comment: Thanks. Marking another time with `wip` just marks `wip`. The steps seem orthogonal

Comment: I said UNmark the `wip`, not mark. I've added an answer that elaborates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Elisp regexp can't express this, AFAIK. (Some regexp dialects can.)

---

But you can do it in two steps:

1. Mark `oil` matches, which will include some `wip` matches.
2. **UN**mark `wip` matches.

---

There seems to be no command `image-dired-unmark-tagged-files`.  But you can define one, just by binding `dired-marker-char` to a space char and "marking" with that.  Like this (untested):

```lisp
(defun my-image-dired-unmark-tagged-files ()
  "Use regexp to unmark files with matching tag.
See `image-dired-mark-tagged-files'."
  (interactive)
  (let ((dired-marker-char  ?\    ))
    (image-dired-mark-tagged-files)))
```

---

Alternatively, after marking the `oil` files you can:

1. Use `* c * Q`, to change all `*` marks to `Q` (or any other char).
2. Use `image-dired-mark-tagged-files` to mark the `wip` files.
3. Use `M-DEL *` to remove all `*` marks, unmarking the `wip` files.

In Dired, you can mark lines with any char, and you can change marks easily. And a line that is "unmarked" is just a line that's marked with a space-char mark.